# Memory consumption when using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, memory-management, multiprocessing

I am using python's `multiprocessing` module to launch some Monte-Carlo simulation in order to speed up the computation. The code I have looks like this:

```
def main():
    (various parameters are being set up...)

    start = 0
    end = 10
    count = int(1e4)
    time = np.linspace(start, end, num=count)

    num_procs = 12
    mc_iterations_per_proc = int(1e5)
    mc_iterations = num_procs * mc_iterations_per_proc
    mean_estimate, mean_estimate_variance = np.zeros(count), np.zeros(count)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_procs)
    for index, (estimate, estimate_variance) in enumerate(pool.imap_unordered(mc_linear_estimate,
        ((disorder_mean, intensity, wiener_std, time) for index in xrange(mc_iterations)), chunksize=mc_iterations_per_proc)):
        delta = estimate - mean_estimate
        mean_estimate = mean_estimate + delta / float(index + 1)
        mean_estimate_variance = mean_estimate_variance + delta * (estimate - mean_estimate)

    mean_estimate_variance = mean_estimate_variance / float(index)
```

Ok, now `mc_linear_estimate` is a function taking *args and creating additional variables inside it. It looks like this:

```
def mc_linear_estimate(*args):
    disorder_mean, intensity, wiener_std, time = args[0]

    theta_process       = source_process(time, intensity, disorder_mean)
    xi_process          = observed_process(time, theta_process, wiener_std)
    gamma               = error_estimate(time, intensity, wiener_std, disorder_mean)
    estimate            = signal_estimate(time, intensity, wiener_std, disorder_mean, gamma, xi_process)

    estimate_variance   = (estimate - theta_process) ** 2
    return estimate, estimate_variance
```

As you could see, the number of iterations is pretty large (1.2M), and the size of all the arrays is 10K doubles, therefore I use [Welford's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) to compute mean and variance, due to the fact that it does not require the store every element of the considered sequences in memory. However, this does not help.

**The problem:** I run out of memory. When I launch the application, 12 processes emerge (as seen using `top` program on my Linux machine). They instantly start consuming a lot of memory, but as the Linux machine I'm using has 49G of RAM, things are OK for some time. Then, as each of the processes takes up to around 4G of RAM, one of them fails and shows as `<defunct>` in `top`. Then another process falls off, and this happens until only one process is left, which ultimately fails with "Out of memory" exception.

**The questions:**

1. What am I possibly doing wrong?
2. How could I improve the code so that it wouldn't consume all the memory?

Comment: First, are you using 32-bit python? If so, that's why the processes are failing at 4GB even though you haven't used up all 49GB of RAM.

Comment: Meanwhile, can you get a rough idea of the memory usage of each of the four sub-steps of `mc_linear_estimate` (by, e.g., running it four times, first just doing and returning `theta_process`, then doing the first two and returning `xi_process`, etc., and watching how long it takes each version to run out of memory)?

Comment: Have you tried setting ``num_procs = 1`` and then using something like ``guppy`` to show heap usage with Python. You could then bracket suspected code with calls to ``guppy.hpy().heap()``